# Where to get StackExchange clientid and secret to integrate StackOpen Id in own Application

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

i want to integrate stackexchange authentication. Where should i register my application and how to i get the client secret?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to allow users to log in using the Stack Exchange OpenID provider, you don't have to do anything - Stack Exchange is not an OpenID *Connect* provider, so it doesn't require OAuth 2.0 credentials*.

If you want to be able to perform privileged actions via [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), you'll need to [register your application on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) and then follow the standard [OAuth authentication flow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

<sub>*Which seems to be a fundamentally stupid aspect of OpenID Connect, since it makes the whole process significantly *more* inconvenient, but I digress</sub>

Comment: I don't get it. I have a registered app. Where do I bloody go to see it's my secret key. I just closed the tab some time ago and forgot the address!?

Comment: @gideon Visit [your apps page on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) and view the details of the appropriate app

Comment: yes. I looked around quite a bit and finally did find it. Thanks :)